# Make a class as Singleton instead of Inject that class every time when using it

Tags: java, api, design-patterns, singleton

I have a class which is used as a common class in my project. That class has the access to some other core classes which were inject in that class, through which I can call some APIs. So when I need to call an API in a class, I usually Inject this common class and use the specific API. But when I inject the common class in many other classes, all the core classes also get injected even I need to use one or two of that core classes. 
This is my common class

```
public class ApiService {

private StuResource stuResource;
private VendResource vendResource;
private EduResource eduResource;
private RKEResource rKEResource;
private AleResource aleResource;
private GloResource gloResource;


@Inject
public ApiService(StuResource stuResource, VendResource vendResource,
     EduResource eduResource, RKEResource rKEResource,
     AleResource aleResource, GloResource gloResource) {
  this.stuResource  = stuResource;
  this.vendResource = vendResource;
  this.eduResource = eduResource;
  this.rKEResource = rKEResource;
  this.aleResource = aleResource;
  this.gloResource = gloResource;
}

{Methods for call APIs}

}
```

So I plan to use singleton patter, so that I can create an object of the common class one time and can use that object everywhere in other classes. 
Help me in this implementation. How can I implement singleton pattern in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

It's bad idea at all - put all functionality in single place.

Create separate services for each business process, give them required resources only. I.e.

```
@Component
public class SchoolService {

    private StuResource stuResource;
    private EduResource eduResource;
    private GloResource gloResource;


    @Inject
    public SchoolService(StuResource stuResource, EduResource eduResource, GloResource gloResource) {
        this.stuResource  = stuResource;
        this.eduResource = eduResource;
        this.gloResource = gloResource;
    }

    {Methods for call APIs}

}
```

then

```
@Component
public class PayService {

    private VendResource vendResource;
    private EduResource eduResource;

    @Inject
    public ApiService(VendResource vendResource, EduResource eduResource) {
        this.vendResource = vendResource;
        this.eduResource = eduResource;
    }

    {Methods for call APIs}

}
```

and so on.

Each of these classes will be singletons as you want.